# Multiple Contrllers in UI-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a application which uses angularjs and I use ui-rourer for routing

I need to have multiple controller for a single page, Is it possible ?

This  is my route.js code

```
  .state(ROUTE.appGroup, {
                    abstract: true,
                    views: {
                        'content@': {
                            templateUrl: GLOBAL.viewPath + '/index.html',
                            controller: 'appCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
```

I need something like

```
  .state(ROUTE.appGroup, {
                    abstract: true,
                    views: {
                        'content@': {
                            templateUrl: GLOBAL.viewPath + '/index.html',
                            controller: 'appCtrl,mainCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `view`, has its `controller`.

And while state can have **more** `views` *(differently named)* -

> **each `view` can have exactly one `controller`** *(default is created if none is passed)*

Either create more views *(to get more controllers into play)*
or just move that functionality to services

Comment: however, it's possible, right? you may pass 'firstCtrl' using state as you say, and 'secondCtrl' for the same view for example paste direct in html using ng-controller... it's ugly, but possible, as I understand = )

Comment: but, why would you do that ? And I don't think it's possible too (or either ? sorry, not native speaker)

Comment: The `ng-controller` directive creates a child scope. So a view template can use `ng-controller` to create a child controller on a child scope but that is not the same as having two controllers on the same scope.

Comment: I know its ugly, but I already did what you said @impregnablefiend..           my app has login and at one case I end up in this situation of using both controller for a same page.looking for a better solution... Thanks anyway..